# Java BufferedImage map colors

Tags: java, image-processing, colors

I am trying to write a program that takes bufferedImage as an input and maps all black-close colors (R<32, G<32, B<32) to black and the others to white for the purpose of OCR (the OCR engine takes BufferedImage as an input). Is there a way to do it without iterating over pixels?
Namely, I tried

```
public static BufferedImage BlackAndWhite(BufferedImage image) {

    ColorModel model = new BlackWhiteColorModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT);
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(model, raster, false, null);

    return newImage;
}
```

Where BlackWhiteColorModel is defined as

```
public class BlackWhiteColorModel extends ColorModel {

public BlackWhiteColorModel(int bits) {
    super(bits);
}

@Override
public int getRed(int pixel) {
    int[] rgb = getRgb(pixel);

    if (rgb[0] < 32 && rgb[1] < 32 && rgb[2] < 32) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 255;
    }
}

@Override
public int getGreen(int pixel) {
    int[] rgb = getRgb(pixel);

    if (rgb[0] < 32 && rgb[1] < 32 && rgb[2] < 32) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 255;
    }
}

@Override
public int getBlue(int pixel) {
    int[] rgb = getRgb(pixel);

    if (rgb[0] < 32 && rgb[1] < 32 && rgb[2] < 32) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 255;
    }
}

@Override
public int getAlpha(int pixel) {
    return pixel;
}

private int[] getRgb(int pixel) {
    int r = (pixel) & 0xFF;
    int g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int a = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;

    return new int[]{r, g, b, a};
}



}
```

However, I end up with isCompatibleRasterException. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Do you need a **Black & White** image or a **GrayScale** one?

Answer (score 0):

(1) You did not implement one of the methods of the contract: `isCompatibleRaster`. Here is an overly optimistic implementation that runs fine given your problem statement:

```
@Override
public boolean isCompatibleRaster(Raster raster) {
    return true;
}
```

(2) `getRed`, `getGreen` and `getBlue` have the same code. Here is a complete program that factors out the common code into a new method called `getColor`. This program runs without error:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class BlackWhiteColorModel extends ColorModel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
         Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
         g.drawString("Hello, World", 20,20);
        blackAndWhite(bufferedImage);
    }

    public static BufferedImage blackAndWhite(BufferedImage image) {
        ColorModel model = new BlackWhiteColorModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();

        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(model, raster, false, null);

        return newImage;
    }

    public BlackWhiteColorModel(int bits) {
        super(bits);
    }

    private int getColor(int pixel) {
        int[] rgb = getRgb(pixel);

        if (rgb[0] < 32 && rgb[1] < 32 && rgb[2] < 32) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 255;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRed(int pixel) {
        return getColor(pixel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGreen(int pixel) {
        return getColor(pixel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getBlue(int pixel) {
        return getColor(pixel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getAlpha(int pixel) {
        return pixel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCompatibleRaster(Raster raster) {
        return true;
    }

    private int[] getRgb(int pixel) {
        int r = (pixel) & 0xFF;
        int g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int a = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;

        return new int[]{r, g, b, a};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
However, my way of creating new image with different colorModel does not work.
If I want to save output of BlackAndWhite(BufferedImage image), no file is created and no exception is thrown. Also text recognition does not work.
Would you know about some other  (functional) way, how to create a new image with different ColorModel but the same data?

Comment: You are expanding the scope, which changes the question, Please accept this answer and ask a new question with the expanded scope.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a threshold operation eg:
[image]

I guess you don't want to iterate over the pixels due to performance issues. If that is true i would highly recommend you to use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/releases.html) just like this:

```
BufferedImage image = null; //use your image here
//Convert image to OpenCv Mat
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
mat.put(0, 0, pixels);

//do something with the Mat e.g:
Imgproc.threshold(...); 

//Convert back
mat.get(0, 0, pixels);
```

The performance especially if you do more image processing is at least 10x faster

Comment: Thank you for this! I would check it during holidays.